# Select Columns other then Columns included in group by clause on condition basis

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I need to group by the records on the basis of `fkId`, `DateFrom`, but also need to select the `TimeFrom` 1st record and `TimeTo` From 2nd record

```
pkID |  fkID  | DateFrom          | TimeFrom  | TimeTo
104  |  20    | 05-02-2019 00:00  | 12:00     | 23:59
105  |  20    | 06-02-2019 00:00  | 00:00     | 12:00
106  |  20    | 06-02-2019 00:00  | 12:00     | 23:59
107  |  20    | 07-02-2019 00:00  | 00:00     | 12:00
```

General GROUP BY will not allow TimeFrom and TimeTo to include in select query.

Data will be just like that, 1 row or 2 rows for Date, 1 row means only AM or PM Only, 2 Rows means AM and PM Both.

```
SELECT fkID, DateFrom --, TimeFrom
FROM table 
GROUP BY fkID, DateFrom
```

So the desired output would be this:

```
fkID |  DateFrom         | TimeFrom |  TimeTo
20   |  05-02-2019 00:00 |  12:00   |   23:59
20   |  06-02-2019 00:00 |  00:00   |   23:59
20   |  07-02-2019 00:00 |  00:00   |   12:00
```

So for Date `06-02-2019 00:00`, Combine dateFrom and DateTo in one row.

Comment: Share your attempt code

Comment: there will be no gaps or overlaps in the intervals? what happens if yes?

Comment: No there will not, Data will be just like that, 1 row or 2 rows for Date, 1 row means only AM/PM, 2 Rows means AM and PM Both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the intervals corresponding to the same group are without gaps and overlaps then you may simply use `GROUP BY`. I assume that `TimeFrom` and `TimeTo` are `Time` datatype.

```
select fkID, dateFrom,
       min(TimeFrom),
       max(TimeTo)
from your_table
group by fkID, dateFrom
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

By putting `group by` clause you can put the `max` in `TimeTo` such as

```
select fkID ,DateFrom ,TimeFrom ,max(TimeTo) 
from <tablename> 
group by fkID ,DateFrom
```

It will give you the desired output.